# Simple javascript Help Requested from expert

Tags: javascript

All JavaScript Expert. I am just beginner to javascript. I have declared some variable and i wanted to view it on my browser but it is not showing. Here are my codes

```
<script>
var year=2014, month = 'Agust', day = "Friday";
document.write('I am showing something'.' year, month, day);
</script>
```

Please help me and descriptive as much as possible. I wanted to write some text with outputting the variable value.

Comment: you have an extra `'` in your write function argument, change it to: `'I am showing something',`

Comment: The string concatenation operator in javascript is the `+`, not the dot.

Comment: What is your source? Are you trying to write this from a book or a website?

Answer (score 0):

There are [good reasons to avoid `document.write()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice), but it works well enough in this simple case, as you're learning your way around Javascript.

`document.write()` only takes 1 parameter, not a list. You'll either need to call it more than once, or concatenate those variables yourself:

```
document.write('I am showing something: ' + year + ", " + month + ", " + day);
```